# How to change the format of a tag in xml file?

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

In an xml file, how to change all occurrence of *annotation* tag which is in format:

```
<manifest>
<project name="something" path="something" revision="some sha"><annotation version="1.2.3" /></project>
</manifest>
```

to:

```
<manifest>
<project name="something" path="something" revision="some sha"><annotation name="version" value="1.2.3" /></project>
</manifest>
```

I couldn't figure out options to do this using xmlstarlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
  --insert '//manifest/project/annotation' --type 'attr' -n 'name' --value version \
  --rename '//manifest/project/annotation/@version' -v 'value' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<manifest>
  <project name="something" path="something" revision="some sha">
    <annotation value="1.2.3" name="version"/>
  </project>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) command should do the job:

```sh
xmlstarlet ed --append //annotation -t attr -n name -v version \
              -r //annotation/@version -v value file.xml
```

The order of the attributes is different, but in XML this doesn't matter.

Comment: Why call `ed` more than once, vs pass multiple actions to a single instance?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I improved my answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I edited a little further to set syntax-highlighting metadata and prevent the code from wrapping off to the right. I still think I like the answer from Cyrus a little more -- a recursive search from the document root is a big hammer, and best used sparingly -- but this was (I think) first, and not inaccurate in any way.